# Is there anything like pointers in Lua?

Tags: pointers, lua

I'm new to Lua and I want to create a table [doh] which would store values like:

```
parent.child[1].value = "whaterver"
parent.child[2].value = "blah"
```

however, most often there's only one child, so it would be easier to access the value like this:

```
parent.child.value
```

To make things simpler, I would like to store my values, in a way, that

```
parent.child[1].value == parent.child.value
```

But to do this I would have to store this value twice in the memory.
Is there any way I could do it, so that:

```
parent.child.value points to parent.child[1].value
```

without storing the value twice in the memory?

Additional question is, how to check how much memory does a table take?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> but the value will be stored as string, so it's a string that needs to
>   be referenced in both places, not table.

First, all types (except booleans, numbers and light userdata) are references - if `t` is a table and you do `t2 = t`, then both `t` and `t2` are references to the same table in memory.

Second thing - string are interned in Lua. That means that all equal strings, like `"abc"` and the result of `"ab".."c"` are actually a single string. Lua also stores only references to strings. So you should not worry about memory - there is only a single instance of the string at a time.

You can safely do `parent.child.value = parent.child[1].value`, you will only use a memory for one slot in a table (a few bytes), no string will be copied, only referenced.

Comment: Thank you for your very insightful comment to my 7y old answer. I am sure it expanded everyone's knowledge about Lua's reference types.

Answer (score 3):

Lua tables (often used as objects) are not copied, but referenced.
(internally, a pointer is used to them)

Comment: but the value will be stored as string, so it's a string that needs to be referenced in both places, not table. Is your answer valid in this case as well?

Comment: now the proper question would be how to check the memory size of a table? This way we will be able to answer the question for sure.

Answer (score 3):

This is a nice application for using metatables:

```
parent={
    child={
        {value="whatever"},
        {value="blah"}
    }
}
setmetatable(parent.child,{__index=parent.child[1]})
```

If an index is not found in the child table (like 'value'), it gets looked up in the table that's the value of __index of the metatable (the first element of child in this case).

Now there is a problem with the above code which we can see as folows:

```
print(parent.child.value) -- prints whatever
parent.child[1]=nil --remove first child
print(parent.child.value) -- still prints whatever!
```

This is because the metatable keeps a reference to the first child table, preventing it from being reaped. The workaround for this kind of stuff is A) making the metatable a weak table, or B) make the __index field a function, instead of referencing it to a table.

```
-- A)
setmetatable(parent.child, setmetatable(
    {__index=parent.child[1]} -- metatable for the child table
    {__mode='v'}-- metatable for the metatable, making it have weak keys
    )
)
parent.child[1]=nil
print(parent.child.value) --returns nil
parent.child[1]={value='foo'} 
print(parent.child.value) -- prints nil, the metatable references to a non-existant table.
-- hence solution B)

setmetatable(parent.child, {__index=function(t,k) return parent.child[1][k]})
print(parent.child.value) -- 'whatever'
parent.child[1]=nil
print(parent.child.value) -- nil
parent.child[1]={value='foobar'
print(parent.child.value) -- foobar, now it will always refer to the table at child[1], even when it changes.
```

If you're really interested to read up on metatables, try reading [Programming in Lua, chapter 13](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.html) and [chapter 17 (weak tables)](http://www.lua.org/pil/17.html). [Lua-Users wiki on MetaMethods](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetamethodsTutorial) might also be interesting.

Comment: thanks a lot for this it looks interesting. I'm still struggling with the setmetatable and using tables as objects in lua, but I will give it a shot. This structure I'm going to use is going to be used read only and no modifications will be made, so it might actually work fine. very cool, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

With C arrays, `parent.child` and `parent.child[0]` are equivalent because of pointer arithmetic. You really shouldn't try to emulate one of the most error-prone, confusing and redundant features of C just because you like the style.